# How to run opencv sample surf matcher?

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to run [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/surf_matcher.cpp) sample code from opencv but I'm confused as to how to run it. It only shows this help message:

```
Usage: surf_matcher[options]
Available options:
Usage: surf_matcher_2.exe [params]

--cpu_mode, -m (value:false)
        run without OpenCL
-h, --help (value:false) 
        print help message
-l, --1eft (value: box.png) 
        specify left image 
-o, --output (value: SURF output . jpg) 
        specify output save path
-r, --right (value: box in scene.png) 
       specify right image
```

From my basic understanding of arguments, I tried many kinds of input arguments as follows:

```
-l box.png -r box_in_scene.png
--left box.png --right box_in_scene.png
--l box.png --r box_in_scene.png
```

But it still did not work. It did have this error but built successfully:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      the default constructor of "SURFMatcher<cv::BFMatcher>" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function    surf_matcher_2  c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\surf_matcher_2\surf_matcher_2\surf_matcher_2.cpp    195
```

I got it to run a long time ago but replicating the old project didn't work either.

Comment: You can check the code and see how it receives the arguments for any of the sample projects in Opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to use for [CommandLineParser](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#gsc.tab=0) is a bit different. You need to put `=` after the option. Like this:

```
-l=box.png -r=box_in_scene.png -o=out.png
```

or

```
--left=box.png --right=box_in_scene.png --output=out.png
```

Be sure to put the correct path for the images.

Comment: For some reason, I have to additionally erase the default false value for help ( `{h help    |              | print help message }`) to prevent it from printing the help message and exiting immediately.